# Being able to exclude certain variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am fairly new to python, I know some but not a lot and I need your help.
I'm trying to make a call from an api, but also trying to exclude different variables when it iterates. here is part of the code (Some things are blocked out due to confidential reasons):

```
def role_assignments(parameter):
    userRoleAssignmentsUrl ="""http://website.com/%s/""" % parameter
    userRoleAssignmentsJson = requests.get(userRoleAssignmentsUrl, headers=headerstest, json=data)
    userRoleAssignments = userRoleAssignmentsJson.json()

    for item in userRoleAssignments:
        userId = item['username']
        responsibility = item['userRoleAssignments'][0]['responsibilityName']

        if responsibility == "Manage Role Assignments":
            print (familyName + " \ " + userId + " \ " + responsibility)

        elif responsibility == "Primary Owner":
            pass
```

Group 1 has both MRAs and Primary Owners
Group 2 has only Primary Owners

With group 1, I only want to print the MRAs, and with group 2, since there arent MRAs, I'd like to print out the Primary Owners. How can I exclude the Primary Owners from group 1 without messing up the output for group 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find a way to differentiate group1 from group2. This is the core of your issue right now. You could try something like:

```
for item in userRoleAssignmentsFamily:
    if item['some group indicator eg. a path name or something'] == 'pathname1_or_whatever':

        # process group1

    elif item['some group indicator eg. a path name or something'] == 'pathname2_or_whatever':

        # process group2
```